# Split String multiple char syntax

Tags: android, string, split

I want to split the input String values separated by one of these char

```
,
;
blankspace
\
/
```

in a double array

My code for `,` is

```
String valueS[] = input.split(",");
        int n = valueS.length;
        double yvalue[] = new double[n];
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            yvalue[i] = Double.parseDouble(valueS[i]);
        }
```

What is the right syntax that I should put in

```
String valueS[] = input.split(",");
```

to split also with the others listed chars?

Comment: split with `;` and `blankspace` will work as same way it is right now working with `,` . but backslash and forward-slash will be tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer your question, [`String.split (String regularExpression)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a [regular expression](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to determine what to split the array by.

This regular expression below will try to split the array by any one of these characters:

- ,
- ;
- space
- \
- /

It is using an "Enumeration" that will match 1 or more of these characters in a row, and then split on them:

```
String[] valueS = input.split("[,;\\s\\\\/]+");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `input.split("[\\]")` will give `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE`

Comment: Ahh I'm forgetting to escape \ for the String AND the regex, updated the answer.

Comment: your updated answer will not split whole data.i.e: `input = "1\2\3"` then it `valueS[0] = 1` .that's it.

Comment: No, it will split correctly, you appear to be struggling understanding how Strings escape characters. 1\2\3 = "1\\2\\3" in a String. "1\2\3" = 1[unseen character][unseen character]. I have just tested my suggested code and it works fine.

Comment: I know the concept.but kindly test it by using log or system.out.print .I found weird output.

Comment: I would use this regex "[,;\\s\\\\/]"

Comment: @DoctororDrive: it's not working either.it is splitting only first element.

Comment: @MehulJoisar please read my comment above, I've already explained to you that you are escaping characters and not realizing they don't print. Please simply println "1\2\3" and you will see 1. This is because "\2" and "\3" are escaped, non-printable characters. When you run a split on "1\2\3", you should only see 1, this String you are testing with is invalid.

Comment: @StevenByle: Yeah,I know the escape sequence.exactly here is what I am saying.if my `input="1\2\3"` and I want output as `values[0]=1` ,`values[1]=2`, `values[2]=3` .how to achieve it?

Comment: @MehulJoisar You are still not getting it. Please ask this as a new question and I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: @MehulJoisar '\2' is a single character. There is no way to split it.

Comment: @DoctororDrive: Exactly,`backslash` tells the system to escape the next character.I know it already.so is there any workaround when the input and desired output as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @MehulJoisar No, since "\2" and "\3" are their own characters, [Octal Escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6). You are basically asking, how can I get "1", "2", "3" out of "1mn".

Comment: @MehulJoisar I would say it this way: "backslash converts itself and the next character to a different character at compile time".